# How to write to a csv , when an attribute is empty or missing from the file?

Tags: python, hdf5

I want to use selected attribute information from my hdf5 file. Some category or subcategory information from the file is missing or is empty. When I try to run the script below it throws an error as it could not find the attributes.

```
def getdata(fileIn, numpy=False, beamNum=1):
    fileOp = h5py.File(fileIn, mode='r')
    beamStrs=['gt1l', 'gt1r', 'gt2l', 'gt2r', 'gt3l', 'gt3r']
    beamStr = beamStrs[beamNum-1]
    try :
        seg_id = fileOp [beamStr+'/land_segments/segment_id'][:]
        lons = fileOp [beamStr+'/land_segments/longitude'][:]
        lats = fileOp [beamStr+'/land_segments/latitude'][:]
        df = pd.DataFrame({
        'segment_id': seg_id,
        'latitude': lats,
        'longitude': lons,
        })
        return df
    except Exception as e:
        print("Something went wrong in getting the attributes")
        if hasattr(e, 'message'):
            print(e.message)
        else:
            print(e)
    #
    else:
        print("Nothing went wrong in getting the attributes")
```

Before

```
## gt1l  --------------- throws ERROR 
df1 = getdata('file.hd5', beamNum=1)
df1.to_csv('outpfile_4.csv',index=False, header=True)
```

After code updation

```
## gt1l  --------------- doesnt throw ERROR 
df1 = getdata('file.hd5', beamNum=1)
df1.to_csv('outpfile_4.csv',index=False, header=True)
```

> KeyError: 'Unable to open object (component not found)'

I would like to iterate the script for 4 beams and if an attribute is an empty or not available skip and write the other attributes to a CSV file.

#### Updated the solution code

Comment: Please post valid (runnable) code reproducing your issue (cf [mcve]) - your current code is not syntactically correct.

Comment: Hope this is more clear.

Comment: Well you forgot to post the full traceback (hint: the traceback is meant to help debugging), but anyway: all you have to do is catch the exception and move on.

Comment: `try:
    (do something)    
except Exception as e:
    print("Something went wrong")
    if hasattr(e, 'message'):
        print(e.message)
    else:
        print(e)
else:
    #print("Nothing went wrong")
    print(" ")`                                                                                                      This solved my problem. Thanks.